# No GitHub Actions workflows detected in repository

Tags: github, dockerfile, github-actions

I am trying to build and push a docker image to Amazon ECR with GitHub Actions by following this [tutorial](https://dev.to/wingkwong/building-and-pushing-a-docker-image-to-amazon-ecr-with-github-actions-on0)

I'm trying to set up GitHub Actions for this [repo](https://github.com/bhavya121999/hello-world-docker-action), so I've created a new [workflow](https://github.com/bhavya121999/hello-world-docker-action/blob/master/.github/workflows/build.yml) in the `.github/workflows` directory.

The **`DockerFile`** is successfully created and build.

[image]

[image]

Now, after creating `build.yml` and committing it into the `master` branch ,when I go to the `"Actions"` tab in the repository no workflows are shown.

[image]

I'm thinking that probably there is an issue in the `.yml file` but no error is visible.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  push:
    paths:
    - app/**
```

How about removing this line? I see you don't have `app/` directory. See more in detail: https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#excluding-paths

Comment: thank u, by making the above changes in build.yml, I am able to see the workflows :-)

Comment: Can you also go through my updated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60611165/error-unable-to-prepare-context-path-not-found-while-building-and-tagging this