# Error: unable to prepare context: path " " not found while building and tagging docker image

Tags: github, dockerfile, github-actions

In continuation of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60589455/no-github-actions-workflows-detected-in-repository)

I am trying to build and push a docker image to Amazon ECR with GitHub Actions by following this [tutorial](https://dev.to/wingkwong/building-and-pushing-a-docker-image-to-amazon-ecr-with-github-actions-on0)

But I am getting the following error :

```
Run docker build \ 
unable to prepare context: path " " not found
```

[image]

Can anyone help me resolve this issue??

**Edit 1:**

As stated by @banyan I have created an `app` directory
[image]

[image]

But still I am getting the same error.

To know more, please go through [this](https://github.com/bhavya121999/hello-world-docker-action)

Answer (score 1):

```
❯ docker build " "
unable to prepare context: path " " not found
```

I think the article expects `./app/Dockerfile` to run `docker build`. but there's no app directory so the action can not run.

Comment: so what should I do, to make that action run??

Comment: for example, just run `mkdir app` then `touch app/Dockerfile` with https://gist.github.com/banyan/e253ab6e9c46d0874f24a89863aaf7ca. then if your AWS credential is correct, you can possibly push to there.

Comment: please go through my updated question, I have created an app directory, but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: I've just cloned your repo in private repo and at least build worked with following. 
https://imgur.com/a/MVJblp4
https://imgur.com/a/OnG2QiN

Comment: I think I am making some mistake in the CONTAINER_IMAGE: myimage:${{ github.sha }}  which is set as an environment variable, in build.yml. Can you please go through that once

Comment: sorry I don't understand what should I do.